# How do I get a list out of a struct?

Tags: list, struct, scheme, racket

I have the given struct :

```
(define-struct clr ( r g b a)
```

and I want to have a list out of it:

```
(list (list r)(list g)(list b)(list a)
```

My current code:

```
(define clrTolist
    (lambda (clr)
    (map list (list clr))))

(clrTolist (make-clr 0 0 0 0))
```

That is the result i'm getting :

```
list (list (make-clr 0 0 0 0)))
```

I don't want the structure name to be shown on my end list.

Comment: `(list (clr-r clr) (clr-g clr) ...)` ?

Comment: It works !  thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You can "access" single values from struct by using this syntax:

```
id-field
```

So in your case

```
clr-r myred
```

will return specific value of r for element myred

You want to create a list, consisting of all values of your element so just try

```
(list (clr-r clr) (clr-g clr) (clr-b clr) clr-a clr))
```

Make sure to understand structs and its definitions. I recommend this Chapter from HtdP https://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-9.html#node_chap_6